# How do queue triggers work in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, queuetrigger

I know there is a [scale controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#runtime-scaling) that monitors events in Azure Functions, but I would like to know how it works at low level with storage queue triggers:

- Does it send requests every x miliseconds to the queue to check for new messages?
- Is there another process that does that job and comunicates with the scale controller?
- Is there a way to see this in action?
- How can we know which storage account and queue is being monitored?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is here https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions but it's probably buried deep within. Btw, do you mean storage queues or service bus queues? Or possibly something else?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I mean storage queues.

Comment: @MauriR Please respond back if you found anything :)

Comment: @Turbo I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I found some explanation, but it talks more about how often it polls for the input binding, and nothing about the low level details about scale controller. Posting it here in case it help anyone.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---polling-algorithm